# Correct output but for the last element in results but I need all results for the complete iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

The loop runs ok through the dictionary with a formula but gives only the result for the final element which the formula holds true. I need the complete list.

My result in the text file is `thulium-167  60.5011675274`.

But that's the last element. It should start with
`actinium-226   6.478791841364163`, then
`americium-240   76.84481748402972`, ..., until
`thulium-167  60.5011675274`.

The code is given below:

```
import math

myList=[] 

with open("data_2.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        myList.append(tuple(line.rstrip().split()))
dic = {}
for index, ele in enumerate(myList):
    key=index+1
    val_1=str(ele[0])
    val_2=float(ele[1])
    val_3=float(ele[2])
    dic.update({key: (ele[0],val_2,val_3)})
    for i in range(len(dic)):
            power= 5/(val_2)
            P=pow(0.5,power)
            cal_grams=val_3*P
            if cal_grams<100:
                outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "w")           
                outfile.write(str(val_1)+ "  "+str(cal_grams)+"\n")
                outfile.close()
```

Why is it dropping just the one final correct result when there should be 23 in all (from a 36 before the loop)?

Comment: What is in the text file?

Comment: You need to append to the outfile, not write to it. (mode a)

Comment: Thanks JeffUK. it now gives me the correct list but the list is duplicated.

Comment: yeah Jeff the result goes like: actinium-226  6.47879184136
actinium-226  6.47879184136
americium-240  76.844817484
americium-240  76.844817484
americium-240  76.844817484
berkelium-245  90.237105788
berkelium-245  90.237105788
berkelium-245  90.237105788
berkelium-245  90.237105788
berkelium-246  37.9121937862
berkelium-246  37.9121937862
berkelium-246  37.9121937862
berkelium-246  37.9121937862        I need one each

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open the file with `"w"` (write) mode, it starts from the beginning; if you used `"a"` (append) mode (which is what @JeffUK is advocating), it would add to the end.

Comment: its an improvement. the result goes like: actinium-226 6.47879184136 actinium-226 6.47879184136 americium-240 76.844817484 americium-240 76.844817484 americium-240 76.844817484 berkelium-245 90.237105788 berkelium-245 90.237105788 berkelium-245 90.237105788 berkelium-245 90.237105788 berkelium-246 37.9121937862 berkelium-246 37.9121937862 berkelium-246 37.9121937862 berkelium-246 37.9121937862     which is a duplication, or triple copy in some lines but i need one copy of each

Comment: What part of your code attempts to deal with this?

Comment: i'm about 4 weeks old in py so this might sound a little gung-ho but im thinking  somthing like "for i in key in range(len(dic)):"  or "for key, ele[i] in dic)"... i'm not syntax proficient but i think u get the idea

Comment: I don't see anything like this in the posted code, probably because it isn't valid Python.  And, no, I *don't* understand what this code is meant to do; I *do* surmise that you have not tried to code anything to deal with duplicates.

Comment: dude, like its the first "for" loop backward counting. Oh thanks i'm trying duplicate removal codes as we speak

Comment: Scott..any tips?

Comment: On how to fix code you haven't written yet?

Comment: line 13(not counting w spaces) above maybe's where the issue is, not sure...im still looking through codes from other pple.